# Python matrix code variables showing unassigned

Tags: python, matrix, undefined

the following code is an attempt to make a successful matrix in Python 3.6.1. As you can see, I have my alpha and bravo matrices assigned and want the code to produce a Charlie matrix (list) filled with the results of multiplying alpha and bravo matrices. My problem is that when I run the module, it says that c is not defined; the same if I request a or b. Pro tips or pointers anyone? Thank you.

```
import math

def matrix(a, b, c):
    a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    b = [[3, 2, 1], [4, 4, 4], [3, 6, 8]]
    c = [[], [], []]
    for c in matrix:
        c[1][1] = a[1][1] * b[1][1] + a[1][2] * b[2][1] + a[1][3] * b[3][1]
        c[1][2] = a[1][1] * b[1][2] + a[1][2] * b[2][2] + a[1][3] * b[3][2]
        c[1][3] = a[1][1] * b[1][3] + a[1][2] * b[2][3] + a[1][3] * b[3][3]
        c[2][1] = a[2][1] * b[1][1] + a[2][2] * b[2][1] + a[2][3] * b[3][1]
        c[2][2] = a[2][1] * b[1][2] + a[2][2] * b[2][2] + a[2][3] * b[3][2]
        c[2][3] = a[2][1] * b[1][3] + a[2][2] * b[2][3] + a[2][3] * b[3][3]
        c[3][1] = a[3][1] * b[1][1] + a[3][2] * b[2][1] + a[3][3] * b[3][1]
        c[3][2] = a[3][1] * b[1][2] + a[3][2] * b[2][2] + a[3][3] * b[3][2]
        c[3][3] = a[3][1] * b[1][3] + a[3][2] * b[2][3] + a[3][3] * b[3][3]
    return c
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code.  Let's look at them one at a time.

1. **Python is zero-indexed.** When accessing an array or list in Python, the first element is `0`, the second is `1`, and so forth.  You defined `a` as

   ```
    a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
   ```

So accessing `a[3][...]` will not work because it does not exist.  `a[0]` is `[1, 2, 3]`, etc.

2. **Empty containers have no index.**  When you defined `c`, you defined a list of empty lists.  The list held at `c[0]` is an empty list `[]`.  So trying to access `c[0][0]` will no work because the zeroth element does not exist (either for reference or for assigment).

It is the same as if you did:

```
x = []
# this will not work:
x[0] = 1
```

If you want to perform a dot product, I would recommend using the Numpy package.  It is designed to handle this kind of mathematics.

```
import numpy as np

c = np.dot(a, b)
c
# returns:
array([[ 20,  28,  33],
       [ 50,  64,  72],
       [ 80, 100, 111]])
```

---

Here is a pure python method to take the dot product of two matrices.  It transposes `b` and generates the sum of the element products for each matrix.  Keep in mind it does NO dimension checking, so it will truncate to the shortest computable result.

```
def matrix_dot(a, b):
    # transpose b
    bT = list(map(list, zip(*b)))
    # generate the dot product
    c = [[sum(xx*yy for xx,yy in zip(x,y)) for y in bT] for x in a]
    return c

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[3, 2, 1], [4, 4, 4], [3, 6, 8]]

matrix_dot(a,b)
# returns:
[[20, 28, 33],
 [50, 64, 72],
 [80, 100, 111]]
```

Comment: Thank you James. I'm all for using the Numpy module now that I know it exists. However, suppose if I chose not to use a module such as Numpy and decided to go to length as I did in the original code above: would it work if I fixed the index positions (starting at the correct position as I did not do), and would it work if I just assigned placeholder values for the c variable (i.e. [[0,0,0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] instead of the empty list of lists)?

Comment: Yes, that would work.  There are more efficient ways to create the `c` output than by hard-coding in the indices.  I will modify my answer to show how.

Comment: I really appreciate the help James. Could you explain the notation in the code you provided, specifically how the dot product is generated? I don't understand the use of xx and yy, or why bT is used: xx*yy for xx,yy in zip(x,y)) for y in bT